# Unable to install grok filter for logstash on Mac

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Tried following commands

```
   gem install logstash-filter-grok
   ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'logstash-core' (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0.beta2) in    any repository
   ERROR:  Possible alternatives: logstash-cli, logstasher, logstash-file, logstash-lite, logstash-logger
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you create plugin pack and than unpack it ? 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html

from your logstash directory:

```
logstash-2.2.2> bin/plugin pack
logstash-2.2.2> bin/plugin unpack plugins_package.tar.gz
logstash-2.2.2> bin/plugin install --local logstash-filter-grok
```

good luck